# What are the ways of making your own linux distro?

Tags: distributions

I have customized my linux to a great extent to meet my specific needs. I want to make a bootable DVD out of it, which I can install on whichever system I wish.

I have heard of a tool called remastersys.

- What are the alternatives to this tool?
- What are the pros and cons of each tool?

Answer (score 2):

Another software package that might serve your purposes is [SystemImager](http://systemimager.sourceforge.net/); there is also [bootCD](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=bootcd), but as far as I'm aware it's pretty debian-specific.

If you want a customized linux distribution that you can run from a bootable CD or USB key without installing anything, you might want to look into [customizing Knoppix](http://knoppix.net/wiki/Customizing_FAQ)

As with many things in linux, it depends a great deal on what you want precisely.

Comment: mkcdrec was pretty good and lightweight (we used both it and systemimager), IIRC it's called rear now, probably easier to google up...

Comment: @MichaelShigorin I dunno, googling "rear" sounds to me like a very risky proposition...

Comment: that's why I mentioned mkcdrec in the first place :-)  IIRC rear's homepage was rear.sf.net, it's redirect by now -- didn't try what's available from yet newer location.

Answer (score 0):

If your system is Ubuntu based use [Ubuntu Customization Kit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uck/)